# Create a list within Ansible var file, and have all items be called for reference in plays

Tags: networking, ansible, cisco, ansible-inventory

Sorry If this has been asked before. I've looked all over and can't quite seem to find anything on it. I'm relatively new to the ansible/coding world, so I apologize ahead of time if my terminology is incorrect.

So, I want to take a list of IP addresses, and assign them all to one variable. As an example, write a `host_var` file, create one variable, and have a bunch of items called to that one variable.

```
prefixes:  
  - 192.168.1.1/24  
  - 192.168.1.2/24  
  - 192.168.1.3/24
```

Then, within the playbook, I want to run a command, and have the output of that command be compared to every line within that `{{ prefixes }}` variable.

Is this possible? How would this be done? If so, can you also limit it to specific items within that variable?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already defined the variable in your example.

Just continue your playbook and use `{{ with_items }}`. Also read the documentation [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/playbooks_loops.html).

```
---
  - name: Test Playbook
    hosts: localhost
    gather_facts: false

    vars:
      prefixes:
        - 192.168.1.1/24
        - 192.168.1.2/24
        - 192.168.1.3/24

    tasks:
      - name: Debug prefixes
        debug:
          msg: "{{ item }}"
        with_items: "{{ prefixes }}"
```